# conda is broken after renaming username in ubuntu

Tags: python, conda

After changing my username on ubuntu 18.04 using the following script

```
exec sudo -i
killall -u [oldname]
id [oldname]
usermod -l [newname] [oldname]
groupmod -n [newname] [oldname]
usermod -d /home/[newname] -m [newname]
usermod -c "[full name (new)]" [newname]
id [newname]
```

My conda environment is broken, as all the packages still point to the old username, 
e.g when typing `grep -r <olduser> *` inside `/home/newuser/anaconda3` 
I get millions of results, and of-course, my environment cannot even find conda.
For example:
`shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1:$Env:_CONDA_ROOT = "/home/olduser/anaconda3"`

If I simply `export PATH="/home/newuser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`, or add it to `~/.bashrc` 
 I get the message:
`bash: /home/olduser/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory`
Which made me suspect there are a lot of other places that still point to the old username.

Comment: You need to change the path within `~/.bashrc`

Comment: no, that points to conda, but doesn't change the internal paths within conda

Comment: Which path did you find in `.bashrc` file?? the old one or the new one??

Comment: in `.bashrc` I added `PATH="/home/newuser/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`, which changed the error from `could not find conda` to `bash: /home/olduser/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory`. Nevertheless, Even if that will work, as all the packages point internally to `old_user` I afraid that even fixing this woun't help.

Comment: I've added an example of a broken link inside conda, that might explain the problem in my opinion

Comment: after editing `.bashrc`, you need to run `source ~/.bashrc`.. did you do that??

Comment: yes of course, please read the errors, if I wouldn't do that, the errors would be different...

Comment: One problem is that all the python scripts have a hard-coded shebang line. Fixing this is going to require manual work. Updating the PATH is not sufficient.

Comment: xref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890159/anaconda-paths-broken-after-username-change?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
 rpl -X old_username new_username ~/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me when fixing a miniconda3 setup on linux.

There are a number of files and directories that have config files and scripts containing hard-coded paths to the old user name. You need to perform a search and replace in all of these files.

There is usually a file in the user's home directory that contains a list of paths to the environment. You can replace the username with a simple sed command as follows:

```bash
sed -i 's/old_uname/new_uname/' $HOME/.conda/environments.txt
```

While you are at it, take a look at the first line of the file `$HOME/.conda/environments.txt`, it is a file path to the location on your system where the rest of the conda environments, scripts and all the other accoutrements that conda lovingly deposits in your system. We'll call this path `CONDA_PATH`. It's possible to run another search-and-replace operation over all the files in that path where the old path is still present (replacing it with the new `$HOME`). The following example uses ripgrep to do a recursive search to find all the filepaths containing lines with the old username, it then passes these args onto `xargs` which calls a `sed` program to replace the pattern in each file. You need to replace `old_uname` and `new_uname` with the terms you are trying to find/replace.

Specifically:

```
CONDA_PATH=$(cat $HOME/.conda/environments.txt |head -1)
paste <(rg -l old_uname "$CONDA_PATH") |xargs sed -i "s/old_uname/new_uname/g"
```